# Using Custom Fonts in HTML 5

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I am using HTML 5 on my project I just want to try using Custom Fonts but it seems the available tutorials online doesn't seem to work, I am totally lost.

I am using 960 grid system for this.
The custom CSS is where I put my **CUSTOM FONTS CSS**.

Here is my code in HTML 5

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>




<meta charset="utf-8">  


<title>LOGIN PAGE</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Administrator">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style/960_12_col.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style/custom.css" />

</head>
<body>
  <div id="main-container" class="container_12">

    <h1>HEAD</h1>
    <form>
      <ul id="main-login" class="push_2">
        <li><p >USERNAME</p> <input type="text" name="cai_uname"  /></li>
        <li><p>PASSWORD</p> <input type="password" name="cai_pass"  /></li>
        <li><input type="submit" name="cai_login" value="LOGIN" /></li>
      </ul>

    </form>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS

```
@font-face{
  font-family: AzoftSans;
  src: url('font/azoft-sans.eot');
  src: url('font/azoft-sans.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('font/azoft-sans.ttf') format('truetype');
}

body{
  background:#666666 url("../images/bg_login_half.jpg") repeat-x;

}
h1{
  font:bold 24pt/2  AzoftSans, Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I will not paste the 960 gridsystem reset and 960_12_col.css it is available
online. I do not know If it affects my CSS.

Thanks
For the reply

Answer (score 0):

When I have errors like this I use chrome(F12) to check that all the links to my files are correct.
I notice your background

```
'../images/*.jpg'
```

try:

```
'../font/*.*'
```

This is the correct formating which looks right on yours, try putting the .ttf first.

```
@font-face
{
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url('Sansation_Light.ttf'),
     url('Sansation_Light.eot'); /* IE9 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works, on supporting browsers, when the [Azoft Sans](http://www.fontspace.com/4th-february/azoft-sans) font has been downloaded, processed with [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator), and installed in the appropriate folder (`fonts`) under the folder of the HTML document. So some step in the process failed. Apparently, you are not using normal FontSquirrel-generated font files and CSS code, as your `@font-face` refers to EOF and TTF files only, but FontSquirrel generates WOFF and SVG, too.

So check out that you carried out the process properly. Also check e.g. the generated TTF file: can you open it, and what happens if you install it as a normal font in your system? Double-check the file and folder names. If problems still remain, set up a test page on the web and show the URL.

Comment: I checked the font its good. I actually install it in my system and it works when I use it directly. font: "Azoft Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif; but its just when I use font-face then I encounter the problems. When I use font squirrel's font-face generator then I encounter another problem the font is corrupted. I am not sure what is  happening?

Comment: The odds are that there *is* something wrong with the font itself. Try loading it from the page I linked to or, perhaps better, directly from the font author’s page: http://www.azoft.com/fonts/

Comment: Thanks Jukka for the help. I tried another font and generate in fontsquirrel site and it worked. Maybe I could use another font as a substitute. Thanks Jukka.